# How to access array's index within another array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, indexing, nsarray

I have this array and I want to access the first index inside another array.

```
(
    (
        1021,
        "String1,
        "<null>",
        "name1, name2",
        P,
        "String2",
        "Link1",
        "String3",
        "String4"
    ),
    (
        1025,
        "String1",
        "<null>",
        "name1, name2"
        P,
        "String2",
        "Link1",
        "String3",
        "String4"
    )
)
```

I tried to NSLog using this code:

```
NSLog(@"ID: %@", [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

But it doesn't work. It gives me an error saying:

```
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I just want to log the value 1021 in the first array of the first array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that either `array` or the first element in `array` is a string.

Separate it out and step through with a debugger to make sure the array is being loaded and accessed correctly:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray /* load from somwhere */];
NSLog(@"%@", array);

NSArray *innerArray = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", innerArray);

NSNumber *objectId = [innerArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", objectId);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the first object in `array` is an `NSString`.

Does any code add a string to said array?

If the first object in `array` were a dictionary, your code would be okay.